# Youtube video player in asp.net with c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, youtube, audio-player

this is my first question in this site.

I am designing and coding a new website nowadays. In asp.net with c#. My question is:
I want to add a music player (youtube player) on default.aspx. In briefly, this website has 4 or 5 other pages and I want to play sounds without interrupting while browsing other page.

Is it possible or not ? And if it is possible, how ? Thanks.
I have researched this subject in this site, but I could not find a real answer.

Comment: Visit this site..... http://www.aspnetaudio.com/

Comment: You want to browse to other pages while still playing a video on default.aspx?  Are the other pages in a pop-up or a modal dialog?  I don't understand how you want to keep a video playing on one page and be able to navigate to other pages.

Comment: Thanks, first. I want to browse to other pages while still playing a video on default.aspx. It is not important the video, only the sound is important. For example, a song...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to do it with just C# or any other purely server side technology.  Once you navigate to a new a page your embedded YouTube player will be trashed.  To achieve the result, you have to do some work on the client side with JavaScript.  The simplest (but possibly least elegant) approach is to have "default.aspx" be a page which contains the main navigation framework within an iframe.  The navigation of the site then happens all within the iframe without refreshing "default.aspx".

A problem with this is that it doesn't update the URL in the URL bar, and the page history is not updated. So you can get around this (sort of) by navigating the container page to hash tag pages, such as "default.aspx#page1", "default.aspx#page2", etc. at the same time that you navigate the iframe'd page to the real content at say "page1.aspx", "page2.aspx".  Your tool for this will be the JavaScript "window.location" object.

A much cooler and cutting edge approach is using something like the [client side MVC technology that has just come out in YUI 3.4](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/app/).

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer. I understood that. I am not against any options. I am searching the best solution. I can use javascript/jquery options. Maybe, cannot use any flash, that's all. And please answer this question: Where can I start ?

Comment: Maybe look at https://github.com/balupton/History.js/blob/master/README.md for JQuery compatible history code.

Comment: Hi again, I want to ask a new question. How can I access youtube video player elements from code behind. For example, suppose that there are 5 video in user's playlist in my web page(not in youtube page), and I want to play first song, than second, and then... How can I do that ? Where can I start from ?

Comment: You'll want to look at the JavaScript PlayerAPI http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/getting_started.html#player_apis and this example could get you started: http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?exp=youtube#working_with_multiple_players  The key thing you'll need to do is use the onPlayerStateChange functions to listen for one video ending, and run playVideo on the next video.

Comment: Thanks. I will look at these links immediately.